# how to implement WSDL web services in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wsdl

i have implemented xml files in my iphone applications but never implemented WSDL web services. So anyone who has worked on it or any sample project for it.

Thanks
Rajni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an old "wsdl2objc" project out there that might do what you're looking for:

http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/